# How to get selected option in Autocomplete (MUI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try to implement Autocomplete component from Material UI in my react app. But I stuck in basic problem - I can get option which user selected.
My implementation the same like in MUI sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/g3dbg?file=/demo.js:129-141

Object which I use for option looks like this:

```
options = {
  name: 'someName1', id: '1',
  name: 'someName2', id: '2',
  ...
}
```

How to get id of selected option?
Important! I need a function which will set this id to api, it means that I don't need to get all suggested option's ids.

Comment: Have you tried the using second parameter of  the onChange method? `onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log(event, newValue.id); }`

Comment: Thank you! I got it